# Using a make rule to call another

Tags: make

I am writing a LaTeX project that I am using a makefile for. I have a clean function to clean the excess LaTeX files:

```
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    \rm *.aux *.blg *.out *.bbl *.log
```

But in some cases I need to get rid of the generated files as well as the PDF file. I have attempted this using:

```
.PHONY: clean_all
clean_all:
        $(clean) \rm *.pdf
```

This does not work as it only removes the PDF file.

My question is how do I invoke the `clean` rule inside the `clean_all` rule?

Comment: Similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8646688/1959808

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make the  `clean_all` target depending on `clean` target:

```
.PHONY: clean_all clean

clean:
        rm -f *.aux *.blg *.out *.bbl *.log

clean_all: clean
        rm -f *.pdf
```

I added the `-f` to `rm` so that non-existing files do not generate an error in the rules (e.g. when you would run the command twice).

(BTW, I never heard of these **rules** being talked about as functions, you might want to recheck your terminology and have more success while Googling things about makefiles).

Comment: I called rules functions as I am new to makefiles and I am used to using the word. I have changed the title to accommodate your note. Although this corrects my problem, the PDF file is a dependency of the rule that produces it so it is not removed anyway.

Comment: @user133987 No problem about the functions/rules, just wanted to make sure you pick up the more common terminology. I updated the answer, because it still had `$(clean)` in it and the `\` (why where those there?). Invoking `make clean_all` should both remove the .pdf and the others.

Comment: Unfortunately, this still does not remove the PDF file. I used the `$(clean)` as I thought that It might be like scripting, where I you call a function (but I see now that you put it as a dependency). Would it help if I added in the entire source of my makefile?

Comment: @user133987 The full Makefile can help, but more important is if there are any error messages. If e.g. there are no `.blg` file you will get a "No such file or directory". You can prevent that with the `-f` option to `rm`

Comment: Yes, adding the `-f` option did remove the error messages and hence allowed the removal of the PDF file. Thank you.

Comment: how can this be extended to a rule calling multiple rules rather than a single rule? So if we wanted `clean1` and `clean2` to be called by `clean`, how would that be done?

Comment: @baxx just put multiple targets on the first line separated by spaces( `clean: clean1 clean2`)